# Facebook share button doesn't display Image and Description

Tags: facebook, button, share

In the Facebook share button when i click popup window appears in that it is not showing image and description. What might be the reason?

```
<fb:share-button class="meta">
    <meta name="medium" content="mult"/>
    <meta name="title" content="name of fan page"/>
    <meta name="description" content="description of fan page"/>
    <link rel="image_src" href="url to image location" />
    <link rel="target_url" href="http://facebook.com/Anti.Social.Development"/>
</fb:share-button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [Open Graph Protocol](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/). As given on their site, here is a full example of a movie page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>The Rock (1996)</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="The Rock"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="IMDb"/>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>
    <meta property="og:description"
          content="A group of U.S. Marines, under command of
                   a renegade general, take over Alcatraz and
                   threaten San Francisco Bay with biological
                   weapons."/>
    ...
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

If you check your [w3c](http://validator.w3.org/), you'll want to change the DocType to `XHTML + RDFa`

Comment: can you give a full working sample code ..please ...its not working for me

Comment: To be honest with you, I can't really do any more of a sample. You need to set the meta properties (some are mandatory - check the link) and then fill the data (in the content part) with the data you want to show up on someone's profile when they share a link to your page). Did you check out the Open Graph Protocol website?